# how to count up then down in one Recursion function?

Tags: java, function, recursion, logic

I want to come up with a recursive function that takes as input a non-negative integer n and produces the list of all natural numbers from 0 up to n and then down to 0 again

For example , if the function is named

```
ArrayList<Integer> f(int x)
```

; when **x = 4** It give a list contaning

> {0,1,2,3,4,3,2,1,0}

How to achieve this ??Can this be done in one function without helper functions such as countup and countdown. 

 Logic Wanted !

Help Appreciated !

Comment: Suppose you had a function that produced a list of natural numbers from 1 up to n and then down to 1 again.  How would you use this in a function that produces a list that starts and ends at 0?

Comment: @Becojo Not a homework man

Comment: You have 3 edge cases for your recursion: 1) when you start, 2) when  your number hits `n` 3) when you go back to your starting point. Think throughly, it's easy.

Comment: @mostruash But what if no global variable is allowed to detect when it hits n?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
public ArrayList<Integer> f(int x) {
    ArrayList<Integer> arr;
    if (x == 1) {
        arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        arr.add(0);
        arr.add(1);
        arr.add(0);

    } else {
        arr = f(x-1);
        int pos = (int) (arr.size() / 2)+1;
        arr.add(pos, x);
        arr.add(pos + 1, x-1);

    }
    return arr;
}
```

In this algorithm I set the base value of x to be 1, of which the numbers generated should be [0,1,0].

If x is larger than 1, recurse to generate the list for x-1, and then insert two values, x and x-1,  in appropriate positions of the returned list,  which is essentially at the position next to the middle value.

e.g

if x equals 2; 
get values for 1 - which would be [0,1,0]
then insert 2 and 1 at the third position (position after middle)  to get [0,1,2,1,0]

if x equals 3;
get values for 2 - which would be [0,1,2,1,0]
then insert 3 and 2 at the fourth position to get [0,1,2,3,2,1,0]

etc...

Comment: Push the allocation to the edge case

Comment: Edited: pushed allocation arr = new ArrayList<Integer>() to the edge case.

Answer (score 0):

recArray is recursive function to return as arraylist in recursive manner.

```
 int x=10;
 List<Integer> result=null;
result=recArray(x,result);
```

if you iterate the result array list, it will have the numbers as you said

```
public List<Integer> recArray(Integer x, List<Integer> result) {
    if (result == null) {
        result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 2 * x + 1; i++) {
            result.add(0);
        }
        result.set(x, x);
    }
    int pos = result.size() / 2;

    result.set(pos - x, pos - x);
    result.set(pos + x, pos - x);
    if (x == 0) {
        return result;
    }

    return recArray(x - 1, result);

}
```

Thanks,
Arumugarani

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> f(int x) {
    if (x==0) {
        ArrayList<Integer> res = new ArrayList<>();
        res.add(0);
        return res;
    }
    ArrayList<Integer> t = f(x-1);
    t.add(t.size()/2, x-1);
    t.add(t.size()/2, x);       
    return t;
}
```